# Автоматическая загрузка картинки при вставке из буфера обмена

Tags: предложение, редактор, загрузка-изображения

Может сделать модную вставку картинок из буфера обмена, как на GitHub?

Сейчас при вставке картинки из буфера обмена ничего не происходит (на GitHub она автоматически загружается куда надо и вставляется в сообщение).

Конечно, можно нажать, на кнопку `Изображение` (или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), затем вставить картинку и затем на `Добавить картинку`, но почему бы не сделать чуть удобней.

Comment: Можете плюсануть на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175123/339911), если это что-то изменит, конечно.

Comment: а мне кажется текущее решение вполне логичным...

Comment: Мне такая фича очень нравится. Бесит, когда попадаются сайты, которые не умеют такое (whatsup web например) и приходится тратить время на ненужные операции, отвлекаться от основной задачи.

Comment: @AK да Вы, батенька, мазохист :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это реализовали! Теперь если картинка находится в буфере обмена достаточно вставить её и затем нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Пост на meta.stackexchange.com: [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/191655).

[image: paste or drag and drop images into WYSIWYG editor]